# I need to vlookup a cell and choose a particular value of priority from the matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So i've a table as such

```
A B C name pri fin
1 0 0 abcd A   A
0 1 0 abcd B   A
0 1 0 dfgh B   B
0 0 1 dfgh C   B
```

I need a formula to obtain the fin column, col A,B,C,name is provided
Each name can have only one value chosen from the cols A,B,C  in the priority order of A>B>C
Here same names have multiple records with either A/B/C values, but only one value should be assigned to each name.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do - give us some specific examples of results

Answer (score 2):

Assuming priorities to follow top-down as per sample data, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=TOCOL(IF(CHOOSEROWS(A2:C5,XMATCH(D2:D5,D2:D5)),A1:C1,NA()),2)
```

Comment: If the order is off, this will take care of priority: `=LET(abc,A1:C1,choice,A2:C5,name,D2:D5,INDEX(abc,MAP(name,LAMBDA(n,MIN(IFERROR(IF(name=n,COLUMN(abc)/choice,4),4))))))`

Comment: TOCOL works only on beta right now. I cannot use a beta version for this.

Comment: @richinrix, `TOCOL()` and other dynamic array function became GA (Generally Available) through the [Excel update](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/what-s-new-in-excel-august-2022/ba-p/3590457) in August last year and thus are ***not*** in beta. Maybe consider to update your Excel to see if that helps?